# Are there any mature PHP clients for Bayeux / CometD?

Tags: php, ajax, cometd, bayeux

I'm in the process of evaluating different AJAX push servers, one of them of course is **CometD** - which uses the Bayeux protocol. Since the application server code will be based on PHP 5.3, it would be great not to reinvent the wheel and use an existing library to publish data via [CometD](http://cometd.org/).

The only class I found so far is [Phomet](https://web.archive.org/web/20090926143240/http://morglog.org/?p=22). However, it is not maintained anymore, obviously still contains debug code and also sometimes produces errors with the latest CometD server (2.3/2.4). Any recommendation is much appreciated! Maybe somebody also came across Phomet and improved it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about mature, but this library looks very well crafted:

https://github.com/advisors-excel-llc/salesforce-rest-sdk/tree/master/src/Bayeux